# Min/Max Value of a short int in C

Tags: c, int, short

**PROBLEM SOLVED: It still doesn't work on Code::Blocks so it has something to to with Codeblocks.**

I have a Problem with the following C-Code. It is supposed to show the max/min Value of a "short int". I'm pretty sure it is right but it doesn't seems to work on my machine.

As the output I just get a zero instead of the desired +32767 and -32768.

If someone could verify for me that it is indeed not a problem in the code but a problem with my software.

PS: I tried running the code on someone else's machine and it worked fine there.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{

short int si=0;
short int si_pred=0;

while (si>=0) {
    si_pred=si;
    si++;

}
printf("%d lowest possible value for a short int.\n",si);
printf("%d highest possible value for a short int.\n",si_pred);
return 0;
}
```

Comment: You could make this considerably smaller if you just included `<limits.h>` and used the standard-mandated constants, `SHRT_MIN` and `SHRT_MAX`.

Comment: `short int si=0; while(si>0)` ... this `while` loop will never enter.  On anyone's computer.

Comment: Note that signed integer overflow is undefined behavior.

Comment: did you copy the file to the other machine or did you hand write it? i suspect the latter.

Comment: Hey WhozCraig. Thanks for the clue. But this is a very early university-assignment for a procedural-programming course and we where only allowed to use while loops. :)

Answer (score 1):

Your `while` loop is terminating early because you set `si` to `0`, and your loop will only run when `si > 0`. Try this, since you know that the largest `int` *should* be at least 1:

```
short int si = 1;
```

Now your loop won't short-circuit, since `1 > 0`.

Or, even better, just set the loop condition to check for `si >= 0`.

```
while(si >= 0) {
   si_pred = si;
   si++;
}
```

Comment: very probably this is the common problem in most cases. "PS: I tried running the code on someone else's machine and it worked fine there." how can be true this?

Comment: I agree. I can guarantee 100% that if you set `foo` to `0`, `foo > 0` is `false`.

Comment: Hey,

thank you! I actually just forgot to do that right now when I typed it again.

On Xcode it works fine! 
But code::blocks still does nothing. So I guess it is a problem with Code Blocks. But good to know that the code was at least correct.

Comment: @DesertIvy: I worked on a project where one day somebody dropped a header that defined `TRUE` and `FALSE` to evaluate to the same value; that was not the most productive of afternoons.  Not coincidentally, it was the last time I used symbolic constants for boolean values.

Answer (score 1):

The problem isn't Code::Blocks.  The problem is that the behavior on signed integer overflow is **undefined**.  You're not going to get consistent results from compiler to compiler, because there's no requirement on the compiler to handle signed integer overflow in any particular way.  There's no guarantee that adding 1 to `SHRT_MAX` will result in `SHRT_MIN`.

The **right** way to do this is to include "limits.h" in your source code and examine the values of `SHRT_MIN` and `SHRT_MAX`.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. 
This is a very early university-assignment for a procedural-programming course and we where only allowed to use while loops and if/else-statements. And that is the solution I came up with.

Comment: @user2920863: then you're going to have to come up with a solution that doesn't rely on signed integer overflow.  Note that *unsigned* integer overflow is well-behaved, but that's not what you need here.